# Download google drive sheet api in php Error

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I want to download the google drive sheet with google login. I follow the quickstart guide. while creating first conslole app. I got the below mentioned error.

[image: Error]

Comment: The above given error is resolved. But now i Got error. ERROR:  Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: {
 "error": "unauthorized_client",
 "error_description": "Unauthorized"
}
 in C:\xampp\htdocs\newsheet\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php:11
8

Comment: Please update your question and remove the old question if it's no longer relevant.